# PHP loop - add days to date

Tags: php, date, loops

I have the following code. It works to add days (daysBetween) to a date (startDate). However, I want to REPEAT it until it reaches the end date. How can I do this??

```
$startDate = "2009-10-11";
$endDate = "2010-01-20";
$daysBetween = 10;

function addDayswithdate($date,$days){

  $date = strtotime("+".$days." days", strtotime($date));
  return  date("Y-m-d", $date);

}

$date = addDayswithdate($startDate,$daysBetween);
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: an array of all the dates

Comment: @alex you can do that with recursive function. See my answer and demo for further detail

Comment: Look into PHP's DateTime, DateInterval, and DatePeriod documentation for the tools you need to do this job.

Comment: Please clarify your description. It's confusing!

Answer (score 3):

You can use following function;

```
<?php

$startDate = "2009-10-11";
$endDate = "2010-01-20";
$daysBetween = 10;
$finalResult = array();
function addDayswithdate($date,$days, $endDate, &$finalResult){
  $tempDate = strtotime($date);
  $tempDate += 3600*24*$days;
  if ($tempDate < strtotime($endDate)) {
    $finalResult[] = date("Y-m-d", $tempDate);
    addDayswithdate(date("Y-m-d", $tempDate), $days, $endDate, $finalResult);
  } else {
    return true;        
  }
}

addDayswithdate($startDate,$daysBetween, $endDate, $finalResult);
var_dump($finalResult);
```

Here is a working demo: **[Demo](http://ideone.com/d78JZD)**

Comment: Thats not what it is supposed to do. It is supposed to add a date from every 10 days starting from startDate till endDate and add to an array

Comment: Could you please give example output in your question?

Comment: if start date is 1-10-2014, end date is 30-10-2014 and daysbetween is 10,I want these days: 10-10-2014 and 20-10-2014

Comment: @alex: Your question was lacking information/input. Yet two people invested quite a bit of time in solving your problem. At least accept either one of the answers and give upvote where upvote is due.

Answer (score 1):

```
   function addDayswithdate($from, $to, $interval){

        $result = array();
        while(true)
        {
            $dateTemp = strtotime("+".$interval." days", strtotime($from));
            if(strtotime($dateTemp) > strtotime($to)) 
                break;
            $result[] = date("Y-m-d", $dateTemp);
            $interval += $interval;
        }
        return  $result;

    }
```

Comment: It returns this. array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "2014-04-01"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "1970-01-02"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "1970-01-03"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "2014-04-27"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "1970-01-05"
  [5]=>
  string(10) "1970-01-06"
  [6]=>
  string(10) "1970-01-07"
  [7]=>
  string(10) "1970-01-08"
  [8]=>
  string(10) "1970-01-09"
  [9]=>
  string(10) "1970-01-10"
}

Comment: but now it returns this array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "2014-04-01"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "2014-04-02"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "2014-04-03"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "2014-04-04"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "2014-04-05"
  [5]=>
  string(10) "2014-04-06"
  [6]=>
  string(10) "2014-04-07"
  [7]=>
  string(10) "2014-04-08"
  [8]=>
  string(10) "2014-04-09"
  [9]=>
  string(10) "2014-04-10"
}

Comment: What I am trying to do is add a date to the array AFTER the number of days ($days)

Comment: you needed all the dates plus the given number,right?

Comment: no... if start date is 1-10-2014, end date is 30-10-2014 and days is 10,I want these days: 10-10-2014 and 20-10-2014

Comment: @alex Which is just what he gave you no? Just in a different format `(Y-m-d)`? In the format in which you asked, an array. Your last comment, sounds like you want just the start and end date; of which.. you already know the first, so why an array for the latter?

Comment: @MackieeE he updated it. but its still not working: array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "1970-01-11"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "1970-01-21"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "1970-02-10"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "1970-03-22"
}